# How should I go about creating a web app using node.js

Tags: node.js, http

I was using flask with python, but I want to develope with node.js because of the libraries, and syntax of javascript, but I am having trouble with finding any good resources for my level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Vuejs to be a good framework with plenty of tutorials and a good learning curve. This is good to build a web app.

If you want a simple server to respond to http requests, I'd suggest expressjs

A mix of the two is good for a micro service architecture.